# How do I remove all the empty unused space in a Visio drawing screen?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I use Visio Plan 2. I didn't find this question.

When I create a Visio diagram the work space is almost limitless. But that means that if I accidentally click somewhere - even worse if I'm using my notebook mousepad and inadvertently drag my finger - the screen will go from the document with coordinates starting at 0 x 0 to some ridiculous -63 x 127. A vast empty space.  And then I have to try to get back to 0x0.

Is there a way to define limits to this empty space?  How about just a Ctrl-Home key combination like Excel to bring you back to actual document?
Sorry if this is an obvious fix, but I've been searching for this answer for a couple years over multiple versions.